# making docker compose use already created database

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to start mysql with nodejs with docker-compose and I want docker-compose to use the connect to the already created database random
However when I run docker-compose the console tells me that it is creating the database "random" which it shouldn't because the database is already created.
Could someone help me out?

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  nodejs:
    build: ./
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=boom
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=passeord
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=random
      - MYSQL_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3002 
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

server.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
const port = 3002;
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // Body parser for fetch posted data
var responseStr = "MySQL Data:";
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/',function(req,res){
   
   var mysqlHost = process.env.MYSQL_HOST || 'localhost';
   var mysqlPort = process.env.MYSQL_PORT || '3306';
   var mysqlUser = process.env.MYSQL_USER || 'root';
   var mysqlPass = process.env.MYSQL_PASS || 'password';
   var mysqlDB   = process.env.MYSQL_DB   || 'random; //this database is already created

   var connectionOptions = {
     host: mysqlHost,
     port: mysqlPort,
     user: mysqlUser,
     password: mysqlPass,
     database: mysqlDB
   };

   console.log('MySQL Connection config:');
   console.log(connectionOptions);

   var connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionOptions);
   
   connection.connect();
 
   connection.query(queryStr, function (error, results, fields) {
     if (error) throw error;
     
     responseStr = '';

     results.forEach(function(data){
        responseStr += data.ITEM_NAME + ' : ';
        console.log(data);
     });

     if(responseStr.length == 0)
        responseStr = 'No records found';

     console.log(responseStr);

     res.status(200).send(responseStr);
   });
    
   connection.end();
});


const router = app => {
    // Display welcome message on the root
    app.get('/hi', (request, response) => {
        response.send({
            message: 'whats up!?'
        });
});
```

Comment: You don't declare any `volumes:` to hold the database data, so every time you delete and recreate the database container, it will start from scratch.  Is this essentially the problem you're having, or do you expect the database data to exist somewhere else (in a host-based or cloud-hosted database, perhaps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@david-maze provides the answer.

You want to do something similar to:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=boom
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=passeord
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=random
      - MYSQL_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
    volumes:
    - your-database:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  your-database:
    external: true
```

Or:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=boom
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=passeord
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=random
      - MYSQL_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
    volumes:
    - /path/to/your-database:/var/lib/mysql
```

The first example uses a docker volume called `your-database`. You could create this beforehand `docker volume create your-database`. Using this mechanism, you will need to run `mysql` one time to create the database. Subsequently, running `docker compose` will reuse it.

The second example uses a directory on your host (replace `/path/to/your-database` with a directory on your host where you wish to create the database. If you have the database stored locally already, you can reuse it this way. If not, you will need to create it locally first. This approach is not 'portable', the compose is tied to your host.

Comment: hello thank you for your answer.  What excactly do you mean with a director on your host ?

Comment: You're welcome! Let's say that your `docker-compose.yaml` is in `/path/to/docker-compose.yaml`, you could have another location on your machine (host), let's say a directory called `/another/path/to/db`. In the `docker-compose.yaml` file you could specify this directory as:
```YAML
volumes:
    - /another/path/to/db:/var/lib/mysql
```
The syntax is `volumes: - [[host-path]]:[[container-path]]`