# How can I use a locally existing MYSQL database inside a Docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I implemented a web application with node and using inside this application a SQL database. I created this database in MYSQL Workbench and everything worked while testing. Now I want to Dockerize this application and the problem is that I don't know how to integrate my database. On Google, I only found articles about how to set up a new database inside a Docker container, but I was wondering how I can access my existing database with all my added entries.

I already tried to connect to my localhost with my root-password and the right port in the yaml file, but the connection fails every time and says that the address 0.0.0.0:3306 is already existing.

Comment: In a container localhost refers to the container, not to the Docker host.  Use the IP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: ...or [How to connect locally hosted MySQL database with the docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44543842/685806)

Comment: ...or [Making docker compose use already created database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65112364/685806)

Comment: Please provide your `docker-compose.yml` so we can see your current setup, otherwise we'd have to guess. The error _the address 0.0.0.0:3306 is already existing_ implies that you try to start another `mysql` server/container or you docker port forwarding on that port.

Comment: Also specify: do you want to connect from your application inside the container to the already existing and already running `mysql` server outside the container? (or do you want to move your database into a container itself? - probably not)